# Oracle insists that table or view does not exist, when it does

Tags: sql, oracle

Turns out this is entirely my bad, the table didn't exist (despite running the table creation code).

I've run the following code, and get the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE Pathways (
    row_ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
    pathway_Source_ID VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
    pathway_Name VARCHAR2(200 CHAR) NOT NULL);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mv_Pathway ON Pathways (pathway_Source_ID, pathway_Name);
CREATE INDEX mv_Look ON Pathways (row_ID, pathway_Source_ID, pathway_Name);

TRUNCATE TABLE Pathways;
INSERT INTO Pathways 
  SELECT rownum, pathwaySourceID, pathwayName FROM (
    SELECT pathwaySourceID, pathwayName FROM Old_Pathways Order By pathwaySourceID, pathwayName);
```

The error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

The "Error at Command line : Column" identifies the Pathways table as the problem.  The TRUNCATE TABLE call works just fine.  And if I run the select statement by itself it runs correctly, producing the output I want.

Comment: Perhaps `Old_Pathways` doesn't exist.

Comment: What client are you using?  If you run it in SQL\*Plus (which isn't a great IDE, but it's sort of the gold standard for proving that something does or doesn't work) it will print the line number and print a "*" next to the column.

Comment: Is the table owner for old_pathways the same as the current logged in user running the script to create pathways? Might you need to `grant select` on old_pathways so it can be seen?

Answer (score 1):

try running this query seperately and see if it works:

> SELECT pathwaySourceID, pathwayName FROM Old_Pathways Order By
>   pathwaySourceID, pathwayName

i suspect the Old_Pathways table/view does not exist or it is in a different schema.